# Calculate technical analysis indicators iteratively or using ta-lib?

Tags: python, ta-lib

Usually, I use ta-lib to calculate technical analysis indicators. But I find at times I need to calculate indicators iteratively, like below:

```
sma = SMA(timeperiod = 10)
while True:
    price = read_price(...)
    ma_value = sma.feed(price)
    # some action do with price and ma_value
    ...
```

Can ta-lib be used in this way? Or there is any other library to use?

Answer (score 1):

Original library doesn't support this way of work. My fork of TA-Lib project named [TA-Lib RT](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt) is designed for that. But no one ever tested its autogenerated python wrappers so I doubt it will work without some bugfixes.